# c# winforms show a 'totals' graph behing segmented category data

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to put together a graph, that has sub category column graphs drawn infront of a total column graph.

Something like this

[image]

Anyone offer any ideas how to approach this, I have tried a few failed ways.

I have tried to make two ChartAreas in the same Chart, but they rendered the graphs separately on top of each other

[image]

I've also tried having 2 seperate charts overlapping each other and setting the background to transparent. That appears to see through both graphs.

```
chart2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
chart2Area1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

[image]

Comment: How the 1st image is coded.  One Chaat? Two? How many series?

Comment: @TaW - no, thats dodged up in excel

Comment: @TaW - or do you mean the 2nd image, with the 2 graphs one top of the other?
So, there is 1 Chart class which has 2 ChartArea classes.  the top ChartArea has 2 Series in it. And the bottom has just 1 Series.
Having multiple Series classes within same ChartArea results in the charted data columns sit next to each other